# seg fault in MPI with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90

I'm parallelizing a Fortran 90 program using MPI and I get some truly bizarre behavior. I have an array ia of length nn+1, which I'm sending in chunks from process 0 to processes 1,...,ntasks-1. Each process also has a list proc_start which tells the starting position in ia that all the other processes have, and a list pts_per_proc which tells the number of points that each process has. The following code works:

```
if (me == 0) then
    print *, 'Eat my shorts'
else
    allocate( ia(pts_per_proc(me+1)+1) )
endif

! If this is the boss process, send the array ia,
if (me == 0) then
    do n=1,ntasks-1
        call mpi_send(ia(proc_start(n+1)),pts_per_proc(n+1)+1, &
            & mpi_integer,n,n,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    enddo
! but if it's a worker, receive this array.
else
    call mpi_recv(ia,pts_per_proc(me+1)+1,mpi_integer, &
            & 0,me,mpi_comm_world,stat,ierr)
endif
```

with no seg faults. When I comment out the line

```
print *, 'Eat my shorts'
```

it seg faults, no matter where I include a call to mpi_barrier. For example, replacing the first bit with the code

```
call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
if (me /= 0) then
    allocate( ia(pts_per_proc(me+1)+1) )
endif
call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world,ierr)
```

gives me a seg fault. I could use mpi_scatterv instead in order to circumvent this issue but I'd like to know just what's going wrong here -- the barriers should guarantee that nothing runs out of order.

Comment: So where _are_ you allocating `ia` if `me == 0` -- and how are the other arrays defined (and their values set)?

Comment: Using `MPI_SCATTERV` is not a circumvention but rather the RightWay(tm) to do it with MPI. Where exactly does the segmentation fault occur? Do you get a stack trace? What MPI implementation are you using? Why are you allocating `ia` only in non-root ranks (may by it was allocated someplace else not shown in the code sample?)...

Comment: I guess I should have clarified -- the full array `ia` is allocated and filled earlier in the program for the process `me = 0`. Then process 0 is supposed to send pieces of it to all the worker processes. Each process makes its own identical copy of the arrays proc_start and pts_per_proc, because I'm going to need them for a later call to allgatherv.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault hidden by a `print *` statement is not unusual, and is often a symptom of memory corruption somewhere in your program.

In cases like these the [memcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) tool of Valgrind may save lot of troubles, though you need to properly [configure the tool for its usage with MPI](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mpiwrap) (and possibly expect a few false positives which are easily detectable).